# how to use cut to manipulate string in ksh?

Tags: unix

I know how to use cut in a text file or in pipe line.
But when it comes to using cut in ksh, I am having some difficulty dealing with it.

```
#!/bin/ksh
...
result=$(cut -d: -f1 string)  //assume string = "first:second:third"
print $result                 //I want to print out "first"
```

when I do this I got my stdout saying that cut cannot open string. Which I kind of know why because cut is for file.
What should I do to archieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result=$(echo $string | cut -d: -f1)
```